# Getting 404 in D2L API

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to create/update LTI link for course but getting 404 when I make request. I am trying this from https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com using Instructor credentials(I can confirm it by calling whoami API). Instructor is enrolled in course (org_unit_id is 6689). Test sandbox is hosted at http://vxxxxxxxx.**brightspacetrial**.com.

`POST /d2l/api/le/unstable/lti/link/6689
Content Type:application/json 
Data: 
{
    "UseToolProviderSecuritySettings": false,
    "Title": "Tiltl2",
    "Url": "https://127.0.0.1:8000/lti/d2llaunch12/",
    "Description": "<p>Points to Local Server1</p>",
    "Key": "",
    "IsVisible": true,
    "SignMessage": true,
    "SignWithTc": true,
    "SendTcInfo": true,
    "SendContextInfo": true,
    "SendUserId": true,
    "SendUserName": true,
    "SendUserEmail": true,
    "SendLinkTitle": true,
    "SendLinkDescription": true,
    "SendD2LUserName": false,
    "SendD2LOrgDefinedId": false,
    "SendD2LOrgRoleId": false,
    "CustomParameters": null
}
Response: Unknown error occured (HTTP status 404)`

I have used correct route and I do get correct response in GET request.
`GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/lti/link/(orgUnitId)/(ltiLinkId)
GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/lti/link/(orgUnitId)/`
I am not sure why it is giving 404. Please help

Comment: I assume that, first, your back-end LMS is running at least 10.4.11, and second that the calling user context for the call has permission to Manage External Learning Tools?

Comment: yes, we are running 10.5.4 on our sandbox and user has required permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to register a new link (with POST), then as per the documentation, you should be providing the [LTI.CreateLtiLinkData](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/lti.html#LTI.CreateLtiLinkData) structure.

Note that, with this structure, you should be providing a `Key` and a `PlainSecret` value: these are, I believe, the consumer key and secret to use for that LTI Link. I'm not sure how the API reconciles having or not having values with these properties and having or not having an existing Tool Provider definition that matches the link's `Url` (so that the TP's key/secret would get used for signing launches of that link, instead of a key/secret defined at the link level).

It's possible that the reason you're seeing the 404 is that the API binding layer can't find a route handler to bind to that matches what you're handling: that is, it's looking at your JSON payload and not able to bind it as a CreateLtiLinkData structure, so it's maybe seeking for another handler, which naturally doesn't exist, thus 404. This "unable to bind to a handler, thus 404" is an unfortunate aspect of the way that D2L's Valence web services implementation works.

Comment: Thank you Viktor, I got this API working as per your suggestion. I used python library d2l_utils for creating POST structures. I would suggest always use language specific utilities offered by D2L.